# The factory class - Design patterns for dummies

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

From *Design patterns for dummies*:

> There you go — you’ve got a factory class

[image]

What I have understood from factory pattern is that ***it helps us to avoid constant code modification whenever a new object needs to be created.*** But the function `createConnection` won't have to be modified it to create and add another object? So how is this helpful?

What's the point that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The factory pattern can be used to limit the number of code changes you have to do. Using your code as an example, imagine you have lots of functions which use database connections

```
void ExampleMethod() {
    var con = new MySqlConnection();

    // do something with con
}
```

And now you want to use Oracle instead of MySQL so you have to change every single line that says `new MySqlConnection` into `new OracleConnection`.

A factory can solve this problem

```
void ExampleMethodUsingFactories() {
    var con = factoryInstance.createConnection();
}
```

where `factoryInstance` is instantiated **only once** with `factoryInstance = new FirstFactory("MySql")`. Changing the entire program to use Oracle becomes trivial now. You only have to replace "MySQL" by "Oracle". You don't have to change the methods that actually use the database connection.

Of course adding a new database engine still means you have to change the factory code, but that's only in one class.

Comment: One question: In the example above do you see a "composition" or an "inheritance"? Connection class type has been used inside the factoryA class. C++.

Comment: I don't think it's either. The factory class isn't composed of connections, it creates and returns them. And there isn't any inheritance involved at all.

Comment: Can the same code be written in C++? I think the concept of public classes is in Java?

Answer (score 1):

That is a terrible design. It is not [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). Most often comparing types at runtime is the sign of a poor design. Polymorphism is the answer. What makes things worse, this factory can produce only one kind of conection, so it should compare the strings once instead of doing it in every call to CreateConnection. What makes it even worse - strings. Why not enum or static ints? (All the errors of this example are of course caused by it's demonstrational nature. But every example of this kind should have a sidenote about the flaws - because it might stick - when you're reading a handbook you naturally asume that what it says is correct)

The proper factory in this case is:

```
public interface ConnectionFactory {
    Connection createConnection();
}

public class OracleConnectionFactory implements ConnectionFactory {
    public Connection createConnection(){
        return new OracleConnection();
    }
}

public class SqlServerConnectionFactory implements ConnectionFactory {
    public Connection createConnection(){
        return new SqlServerConnection();
    }
}
```

Insted of:

```
FirstFactory factory = new FirstFactory("Oracle");
```

You would have:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new OracleConnectionFactory();
```

When you want a new kind of Connection, you would *add* a new factory, and changed this one line, you wouldn't have to *modify the existing classes*.

Comment: What you described is abstract factory method and not Factory method.